# How to check if a string is a date value / date string in react

Tags: reactjs, string, datetime, momentjs

I want to check if a string value is a date or not.
I have used different ways to recognize , but all of them recognize "111" (and some other string like this) as date.

Actually, I have different string that user entered them like: text, number, IP address, date, range, date time , etc. I saved all of them as string (because I have to save them as string in my project)

Now, in other section of my project, I want to check if a string is date (with this format `2020-09-23 00:00:00`), show that different and convert it to date with moment.

I used this ways:

1-

```
 moment(myString, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").isValid()
```

2-

```
Date.parse(myString)
```

but all of them return `true` for string "111" or "1234" and so on.

I want to my condition return `true` if and only if mySting has `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` format like this: `2020-09-23 00:00:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try parsing the string into date? so something like `new Date(dateString)` that will either spit out a date object or a string saying date is invalid. In your case you should try this `const isDateValid = (date = "") => { let parsedDate = new Date(date); return parsedDate.toString() !== "Invalid Date"; }` That should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you but this not working correctly. your code still return `true` for number string that has length<6. for example, your solution return true for `111` string.

Comment: In that case the only thing I can think of is to validate the input using regex and then trying to find out if date is valid or not. I think this should do the trick `const isDateValid = (date = "") => {
    const dateRegex = /^\d\d\d\d-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) (00|[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])$/;
  if(!dateRegex.test(date)) return false;
    let parsedDate = new Date(date);
    return parsedDate.toString() !== "Invalid Date";
}`